# How to convert Blender as a Python module into an easily downloadable package?

Tags: python, scripting, development, compile

I have successfully converted Blender 3.2 into a python module on Windows 10 and can import it into my Python 3.10 scripts and run bpy commands.

As described in [Building Blender as Python Module on Windows 10](https://skwrites.in/building-blender-as-python-module-on-windows-10/) the folder structure for Python310 looks like this:

[image: Image of Python310 folder structure containing 3.2 Blender folder.]

- Note that it contains the 3.2 folder from Blender 3.2 (alpha as of writing this)

And the folder in `\Python310\Lib\site-packages` containing bpy.pyd and all .dll files looks like this:
[image]

- Note that I have other modules installed like Django, CAPTCHA, Rest Auth, etc...

My question is; How do I create a downloadable package like Python's `requests` module? (it doesn't have to be on pypi, just downloadable from a git repo)

My goal is to deploy this bpy module to a Windows server running docker with a Django Rest_Framework API. I want to be able to tell DockerFile: Download bpy3.2 at this GitHub link when deployed or possibly add it to a `requirements.txt` file. What I don't understand is how the file structure of the folders above will affect the download and implementation into python310. Would it be easier to just use a Virtual Env and copy it to the container somehow?